# Exception inside using initialization

Tags: c#, .net, using

I read many threads about the `using` keyword in C#, but I couldn't find anyone with the same question.
Reading [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C) interesting article, it says that the using statement is basically equivalent to a try/catch block:

```
MyResource myRes= new MyResource();
try
{
    myRes.DoSomething();
}
finally
{
    // Check for a null resource.
    if (myRes!= null)
        // Call the object's Dispose method.
        ((IDisposable)myRes).Dispose();
}
```

What really makes me going mad is that the object initialization `myRes= new MyResource()` is still outside of the try/catch block, so if something goes wrong during the initialization (oh, and it does!) I have no other way to handle it than using a normal try/catch block.

Is this correct or am I missing something? In my opinion, this makes the sense of the `using` statement partially useless.

I also tried something like this:

```
using (MyResource myRes)
{
    myRes = new MyResource();
    myRes.DoSomething();
}
```

but the compiler don't like this, so it is not possible to bring the initialization inside of the try block.

This seems so strange to me that I think that I must be missing something. Could anyone explain me the reasons behind this?

Comment: if `new MyResource();` fails and `myRes` stills `null`, what do you want to `Dispose`?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if the constructor fails, the exception will be thrown *instead of the reference being returned* - so the calling code has nothing to dispose.

Basically, constructors need to be careful. If an exception is thrown in an exception, the constructor needs to make sure no resources are leaked, because nothing else is going to get a chance to clean up.

Comment: This makes sense. So I'd say that it is a good practice to avoid using `using` when the constructor may throw an exception, and put it in a try/catch/finally block instead. Correct?

Comment: @bluewaves: No, I think you've missed the point. Using a `try/catch/finally` block won't help you, because you still won't have anything to dispose. What benefit do you think it would give you?

Comment: Sure, I won't have anything to dispose, but I will catch the exception and my program won't crash. If I only use the `using` block, an exception within the initialization will result in an uncatched exception.

Comment: @bluewaves: That's the case regardless of anything else though - it has nothing to do with whether the exception is thrown in the constructor or elsewhere. I rarely use `catch` blocks personally - preferring to catch most exceptions in a few common places high up the call stack - but where I *do* want them with disposable resources, I usually nest a `try/`catch` within a `using` statement or vice versa.